# Unauthenticated AWS users with Cognito Sync and JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to figure out the best way of supporting authenticated and unauthenticated users in my app.

I would like to use CognitoSync to maintain user state.  However, with unauthenticated users, I get a new IdentityId each time the app starts, thus the previous state is not found.

I have experimented with explicitly saving the IdentityId into localstorage, and then manually inserting into the credentials if needed; that seems to work okay but it feels like I'm doing something I don't need to be doing.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on the *right* way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Getting a new id each time definitely shouldn't be happening. Which SDK version are you using? Can you share a few snippets on how you're initializing/using the client?

Comment: @JeffBailey - thanks Jeff.  After trying to tease out a subset of code, I found the problem was caused by passing an empty `logins` array in the parameters.  Once I removed that it was fine.

Comment: Always the tiny little stuff, happy to hear it's good to go though!

Comment: @MikeM is there any chance you could post a subset or example of how you're getting the IdentityID? I'm having trouble finding documentation on using unauthenticated users and I essentially want to do the same thing (maintain state for them for a bit until they log in). Thanks!

Comment: @virtualandy - at least in the JavaScript API, the identityId is populated after the addCognitoCredentials method is called.  It's then accessible via AWS.config.credentials.identityId.  If/when they do authenticate, I move their unauthenticated state info to the new identiyId.

Comment: @MikeM awesome, thanks for the extra explanation!

Comment: @MikeM or @Jeff Bailey I'm still struggling with this a bit. It's essentially the same question (or so it seems) but I can ask elsewhere/rephrase as new if needed.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/virtualandy/yLm7k1ba/1/) demonstrating my confusion. Every time I call `.getId({'IdentityPoolId':'<unauthenticated_pool_id>'}, function...)` I get a new ID as a result. Excuse the hacky code and highly probably I'm not grasping the concept of unauthenticated IDs.

Comment: @virtualandy - My grasp is probably only slightly better :)   Anyways, you shouldn't need to call getId.  Just reference from AWS structure like  mentioned above after you get the credentials.

Comment: @MikeM haha, thanks. Interesting...when I looked for something in `AWS.config.credentials` it was always null. I guess I don't understand how to get credentials via the JS SDK. I was under impression I could short cut it via the IdentityPoolId and that JSFiddle example. I'll work on it a bit more, thanks for the tips.